# TYPO3 extension thought experiment: Editing a news entry and the comment entries in one go?

Tags: typo3

As i posted a similar, but much more complex/long/case specific question yesterday, i thought of reformulating it and make it more easy to relate to. But keep in mind, it is just a simplified, not real life example, so i can't provide real life code. **I just need to know if the idea is possible or if i should search for another solution and don't waste time on it**:

I have a class called news. This class of course has an edit and update Action in its specific controller. Next to this it has objects of the class comment attached to it (the relation to these comment objects is stored in an Object Storage). Normally, as you can imagine, you can edit the news and the comments seperately as they have seperate controllers and their Actions. BUT: Is there a way to edit the news object/record and the comments of it in one go, hypothetically?

So basically the editAction of the news class assigns the news object with its corresponding Object Storage property "comments" to the view and in the view i can easily access each comment through their relation in the Object Storage and implement them into a form to also change their values...

The simplified updateAction would look like this (keep in mind the property "comments" of the news is the Object Storage for the comments):

```
       public function updateAction(\...\...\Domain\Model\news $news)
        {
            $objectManager = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\ObjectManager');
            $commentRepository = $objectManager->get(\...\...\Domain\Repository\commentRepository::class);

             foreach($news->getComments() as $comment){
                $commentRepository->update($comment);   
            }

            $this->newsRepository->update($news);
            $this->redirect('list');
        }
```

The (simplified) Edit template would look like this:

```
<f:form action="update" name="news" object="{news}" >

<f:form.textarea property="newsentry" cols="40" rows="15" /><br />

<f:for each="{news.comments}" as="comment" >
        <f:form.textarea property="commententry" value="{comment.commententry}" /><br />
</f:for>

<f:form.submit value="Save" />
```

Do you see the problem in this hypothetical example? Only the news object is passed to the updateAction and of course the Object Storage property ("comments") where the relations to the corresponding comment objects are stored are passed to the updateAction, not the changed comments themselves. So only the changed newsentry is persisted not the changed commnetentries, even though i have the necessary code in the updateAction to do so.

So, guys... Is there any solution to this problem or is it not possible at all and i should look for other means to find a solution and don't waste time on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I handle it in my projects by getting the key of each comment, so you can use the property. Example:

```
<f:for each="{news.comments}" as="comment" key="commentIndex">
    <f:form.hidden property="comments.{commentIndex}.__identity" value="{comment.uid}" />
    <f:form.textarea property="comments.{commentIndex}.commententry" value="{comment.commententry}" />
</f:for>
```

Important is the `__identity` argument to give Extbase the important attribute which comment record is edited here.

You don't need to update each comment in the `updateAction`, it's done automatically by updating the news record.

Comment: My TYPO3 throws an error:

Exception while property mapping at property path "": Property "comments" was not found in target object of type "...\...\Domain\Model\news".

Comment: Sry, it was my error. Still even though there is no exception anymore, the records are still not persisted.

Comment: Can you give me the output of the generated HTML for that comments part?

Comment: The problem is, that my actual project has nothing to do with comments and news, just uses the general principle. I just used the simplified comments/news example to make it more relatable.

Comment: Well, here is my initial question regarding the actual project: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48516645/typo3-extension-developement-attached-objects-of-a-relation-arent-edited-when

Comment: Either way i keep trying it with your solution. But there is something that i don't understand yet: For the commententry property you basically use the Object Storage and the key f the object before the actual property. Why is that. And is the key necessary?

Comment: You need to have an array (to save as objectstorage) and as long fluid is not able to handle empty arrays like e.g. `name="news[comment][][title]"` you need to set a key into this empty field.
The key will not be written or handled in any way, it's only a workaround. The exact update or create handling is done by having an `__identity` or not.

Comment: I see. The interesting thing is, that in my example, whenever i use just the property "commententry" instead of "comments.{commentIndex}.commententry" and use value="{comment.commententry}", the output shows basically the existing commententry, but if i use your example for the property, the commententry doesn't get output. What do you think went wrong?

(well in my real life example the property is named differently and of checkbox, but i use the example terminology here to not confuse you)

Comment: ... in addition to what i just wrote: Can it be that the specific object is not correctly addressed and therefore not changed? I mean if the commententry doesn't get the value comment.commententry assigned, then the same happens with __identity... It doesn't get the comment.uid. But why?

Comment: Another step closer to the truth:
`<f:form.checkbox property="zugewCheckobject.{CheckobjectIndex}.checked" value="true" /><br />` This is from my real life project. The only difference is that the form is a checkbox. If i set the value to "true" instead of using the `"{object.property}"` for value, the Object Storage gets persisted with making all the values for the property "checked" true. But the checkbox itself does nothing and is always unchecked.

Comment: OK, it works now.... Your solution wasn't at fault, it was me forgetting the checked argument. Sry for having bothered you. I marked your answer as the correct one.